# Microsoft Graph API Token Validation - Signature validataion Failed in API server

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, adal.js

In my application i was used Azure AD token based get the user context.

I was implemented azure ad implict flow in swagger that  return token in validate and working fine. but i tried for sharepoint / JQuery / Mobile application using MSAL or ADAL Js based get the token. that token passed in header. but, the throw the error IDX10511 signature validation failed.

I search many website. i am not get how to validate the Microsoft Graph API Token.

Anyone knows please share your knowledge. or any other way to validate the Graph API signature.

in my sample code here

```
  IList<string> validateAudience = new List<string>() { "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000", $"{clientId1}", $"{clientId}", "https://graph.microsoft.com", "https://example.sharepoint.com", $"api://{clientId1}/user.read", $"api://{clientId}/user.read", $"api://{clientId}" };
        var metaDataUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/.well-known/openid-configuration";
      
        //OpenIdConnectConfiguration openidconfig = OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(metaDataUrl, CancellationToken.None).Result;
        var configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>($"https://sts.windows.net/{TenantId}/.well-known/openid-configuration", new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
        var openidconfig = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;

    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
   .AddAzureAd(options =>
    {
        Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
    })
        .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, _ =>
          {

              _.Audience = Configuration["ClientId"];
              _.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/v2.0";
              _.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
              {
                  ValidateAudience = false,
                  ValidAudiences = validateAudience,

                  ValidateIssuer = false,
                  ValidIssuer = "https://sts.windows.net/{TenantId}/",
                  ValidIssuers = new List<string>() { "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/v2.0", "https://sts.windows.net/{TenantId}/" },

                  ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                  IssuerSigningKeys = openidconfig.SigningKeys,

                  RequireExpirationTime = true,
                  ValidateLifetime = false,
                  RequireSignedTokens = false,
              };
              _.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
              _.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
              {
                  OnChallenge = context =>
                  {
                      return Task.CompletedTask;
                  },
                  OnMessageReceived = context =>
                  {
                      return Task.CompletedTask;
                  },
                  OnForbidden = context =>
                  {
                      return Task.CompletedTask;
                  },
                  OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                  {
                      return Task.CompletedTask;
                  },
                  OnTokenValidated = context =>
                  {
                      return Task.CompletedTask;
                  }
              };
          });
```

I was debugged the application MSAL and ADAL JS Based Generated token always get OnAuthenticationFailed  event and it's throw exception

> "IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey, KeyId: '1E50B4475DAC931359D564309A3385FFAB7FB431', InternalId: 'f61f7746-3cff-4557-8b2c-b47fad9cf1e3'. , KeyId: 1E50B4475DAC931359D564309A3385FFAB7FB431"

Parsed JWT Token Image

[image]
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide a screenshot.

Comment: @CarlZhao i was added jwt parsed image.

Comment: The access token is unique, that is, a token can only correspond to one api. Check your `aud` and make sure it is the only recipient of your token. I noticed that you have defined a lot of apis in your code. If you only need to verify the MS graph api, then you only need to set the scope to `'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'`.  Then the token parsed out like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA4Fy.png

Comment: @CarlZhao aud: is use either resource id or application id. in msal library return application id  aud property. please refer application and resource id : https://www.shawntabrizi.com/aad/common-microsoft-resources-azure-active-directory/

Comment: You should first determine which api you are calling, if you are calling MS graph api, please set the scope to:'`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`', if you are calling For custom api, please set the scope to:'`api://{app client id}/.default`'.